# Convert code from Matlab to R

Tags: r, matlab, loops, matrix, spatial

[Example of My Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW3f1.png)

I have three matrix csv data files that I need to flatten and combine in R, so that I have three columns (Lat, Long, Data). The code I have for this is in matlab, but I need to convert this to R. Any thoughts? This is the matlab code that does this:

```
LON=csvread(‘LONGITUDE.csv’);
LAT=csvread(‘LATITUDE.csv’);
SM=csvread(‘soil_moisture20151008.csv’);
xyz=zeros(101*210,3);
k=0;
for i=1:101
    for j=1:210
        k=k+1;
        xyz(k,1)=LAT(i,j);
        xyz(k,2)=LON(i,j);
        xyz(k,3)=SM(i,j);
    end
end
csvwrite(‘xyz.csv’,xyz);
```

So far this is how I have changed it in R:

```
LON<-read.csv("LONGITUDE.csv", header = T)
LAT<-read.csv("LATITUDE.csv", header = T)
ET<-read.csv("actual_ET20100101.csv")

xyz=matrix(3,101,210)
k=0
for (i in 1:101){
    for (j in 1:210){
        k=k+1
        xyz[k,1]=LAT[i,j]
        xyz[k,2]=LON[i,j]
        xyz[k,3]=ET[i,j]
    }
}

write.csv("xyz.csv",xyz);
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Finally, I have a whole directory of files that I need to run this script on, so any ideas on how to apply this to a directory would be great. The LAT/LON files don't change, just the data files. 
Thank you!!

Comment: `xyz=matrix(3,101,210)` is clearly not the same as `xyz=zeros(101*210,3)`.

Comment: Btw., you really don't want to use such a loop in R. Use a vectorized approach for efficiency.

Comment: It would probably help to post a snippet of the data from each source (e.g., `dput(LAT[1:6, 1:6])` ). As @Roland said: it is unclear what it is you are trying to do without seeing the data. A loop like you are using is almost certainly not the cleanest approach

Comment: Pictures of data input are not useful for re-creating your problem. (Of note, do not use `header = TRUE` if you do not, in fact, have a header.) Based on your description, I believe that the sample data I generated in my answer recreates your use case and should address your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your data correctly, you have a large number of matrix files, where each index (row/column position) is assigned to the same data value. That is, (1,1) in each matrix gives the value of interest for the 1st data point, and (1,2) gives values for a different data point.

In that case, you should just be able to convert them all to a matrix, extract the values as a vector, then stitch them together.

To illustrate, here are three identical data.frames (so that we can see if they align correctly:

```
A <- B <- C <-
  data.frame(matrix(runif(36), nrow = 6))
```

Each data.frame is this:

```
         X1        X2          X3        X4        X5        X6
1 0.2462450 0.6887587 0.216578122 0.5982332 0.2402868 0.9588999
2 0.5924075 0.7511237 0.813704807 0.6892747 0.6253069 0.4648226
3 0.7482773 0.4808986 0.006036452 0.6576487 0.5752148 0.5554258
4 0.8545323 0.6822942 0.654128179 0.6582181 0.8173544 0.5191778
5 0.1748737 0.7456279 0.992209169 0.4468014 0.3491022 0.9736064
6 0.7189847 0.3424291 0.581840006 0.1460138 0.8071445 0.2920479
```

Then, I put them all in a `list` (named, so that the columns come out named):

```
myList <- list(A = A, B = B, C = C)
```

Then, we loop through the list, converting each data.frame to a matrix, then extracting the values as a vector. Then, I convert the resulting list to a data.frame to get the column/row behavior you likely want (data.frames are just lists with special properties; each column is an element of the list, but data.frames assumes the value orders match). Note that I am using `magrittr`/`dplyr` piping to simplify the nesting in the code:

```
flattened <-
  lapply(myList, function(x){
    as.matrix(x) %>%
      as.numeric()
  }) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Then, the head of this (from my randomization) looks like:

```
          A         B         C
1 0.2462450 0.2462450 0.2462450
2 0.5924075 0.5924075 0.5924075
3 0.7482773 0.7482773 0.7482773
4 0.8545323 0.8545323 0.8545323
5 0.1748737 0.1748737 0.1748737
6 0.7189847 0.7189847 0.7189847
```

Of note, you mentioned that you may have multiple data sources that you want to merge -- as long as you load them all up into this list, the approach will generate a column for each.

Comment: @Roland see "example of my data" to see how the data is structured. Its three matrices (Lat, Lon, Data)  that need to be combined and flattened so that I end up with three columns. Lat, Lon, Data.

Comment: one more question: so if I want to apply this to a directory of over 2000 files, how would i do that. The Lat and Lon files remain the same, but the data files will vary. I tried a few things but no luck yet

Comment: I would suggest that you post that as a separate question -- it is beyond the scope of what you have asked here. It will likely hinge on `list.files` and you should start there to do background research before posting another question. Feel free to drop the link to the new question in the comments here after you post it